# reading textfile to find an active product key

Tags: vb.net, security, textbox, key, text-files

I have made a product key system that has a textbox and when I hit activate it reads a txt file with active product keys and it checks to make sure the textbox text is the same as one of the active codes in a text file. However, if I enter an invalid code, it freezes to death! maybe a bad code? Here is my code:

```
    Dim code As String
    code = TextBox1.Text

    Try
        Dim sr As IO.StreamReader = New IO.StreamReader("C:\Users\Chris\test.txt")
        Dim line As String

        Do
        line = sr.ReadLine

        Loop Until line = code
        sr.Close()
        my.settings.registered=True
        MsgBox("Your code is valid")

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("You have entered an invalid code, please try again", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)



    End Try
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not checking to see if you have reached the end of the file so your application is probably throwing an exception that you are not catching. you need to check to see if you have reached the end of the stream:

```
Do Until sr.EndOfStream
    ....
Loop
```

should fix it

Note: you should also dispose of your StreamReader object after you have finished. But better still wrap this in a [Using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx) block so you don't have to remember to do it!

Better to wrap all this into a function like so:

```
Private Function IsValidCode(ByVal code As String) As Boolean
    Dim line As String
    Using sr As New StreamReader("yourfile")
        Do Until sr.EndOfStream
            line = sr.ReadLine
            If line = code Then Return True
        Loop
    End Using
    Return False
End Function
```

Comment: I tried that and it stopped the infinite loop, but how would I make is like if it doesn't loop until line=code then msgbox("failed") or if looped until line=code then my.settings.registered=true form1.show me.hide

Answer (score 0):

Try change your loop ..

```
Do
    line = sr.ReadLine

    if line = code then

      '.................
      exit do 

    end if

Loop Until line is Nothing
```

Comment: I just changed it but it only reads the first line...it counts the second line or more "failed"